# Need to connect to Salesforce CRM using .Net C#

Tags: c#, salesforce, crm, connector

I am new to the Salesforce CRM world and i need to write a generic connector/plugin in C# to connect to Salesforce CRM DB for one of our product. 
Idea is that for which ever customer we want to provide our services to, we would obtain all their CRM data by using our plugin and store it locally into our DB. Although, our local DB would also be stored on Cloud, however initially even if we can figure out first how to do it with on premise SQL DB, we can migrate it later on.

Also, we would want some sync capability onto this connector which can continuously sync data from CRM on a periodic basis. Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should provide some attempts and the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

- Use the Salesforce API and build a wrapper yourself. You need to setup developer account etc.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm
http://www.maatech.com/dotnetframework/using-salesforce-com-in-c.html

- Use a 3rd part DLL to connect to Salesforce and make it easy to work with Salesforce objects. Most of the DLLs are paid versions with trial facility.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a639fe58-54b6-429b-b875-1584c365afb7
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f6ecab53-dec5-4aca-b559-ce39315f6781

Answer (score 0):

There are a set of prerequisites that you need to get done in order to interact with salesforce API using the C# .NET.

Username and Password (salesforce logins)
SOAP API (WSDL file)
Security Token